# Read DNS(mDNS) responses

Tags: c#, .net, dns, packet, mdns

For a project, I've to read mDNS responses.

I read the IETF doc(and tcpguide, which contains a lot of [schema](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessageResourceRecordFieldFormats-2.htm)) , and I think I'm respecting them, but I've an issue.

Often I'm trying to read my stream, but the stream is too short for data I'm trying to read.

I had several cases, and I think I'm missing something.

One concrete example:
I receive this(I've made a small "response parser" to see what I receive and "decode" it:

```
0000000000000000  0              ID
1                 True           IsResponse
0000              0              Opcode
1                 True           Authoritative
0                 False          Truncation
0                 False          Recursion desired
0                 False          Recursion available
000               000            Zero
0000              0              RCode
0000000000000000  0              Question count
0000000000000100  4              Answers count
0000000000000000  0              Authority count
0000000000000000  0              Additional count
Answers:
00001001          9              Size
01011111          _
01110011          s
01100101          e
01110010          r
01110110          v
01101001          i
01100011          c
01100101          e
01110011          s
00000111          7              Size
01011111          _
01100100          d
01101110          n
01110011          s
00101101          -
01110011          s
01100100          d
00000100          4              Size
01011111          _
01110101          u
01100100          d
01110000          p
00000101          5              Size
01101100          l
01101111          o
01100011          c
01100001          a
01101100          l
00000000          0              Size
00000000          0              Size
00001100          12             Size
00000000
00000001          ?
00000000
00000000
00011100          ?
00100000
00000000
00010111          ?
00001111          ¤
01011111          _
01110000          p
01100100          d
01101100          108            Size
00101101          -
01100100          d
01100001          a
01110100          t
01100001          a
01110011          s
01110100          t
01110010          r
01100101          e
01100001          a
01101101          m
00000100          ?
01011111          _
01110100          t
01100011          c
01110000          p
11000000          ?
00100011          #
11000000          ?
00001100          ?
00000000
00001100          ?
00000000
00000001          ?
00000000
00000000
00011100          ?
00100000
00000000
00001011          ?
00001000
01011111          _
01110000          p
01110010          r
01101001          i
01101110          n
01110100          t
01100101          e
01110010          r
11000000          ?
01000100          D
11000000          ?
00001100          ?
00000000
00001100          ?
00000000
00000001          ?
00000000
00000000
00011100          ?
00100000
00000000
00000111
00000100          ?
01011111          _
01101001          i
01110000          p
01110000          p
11000000          ?
01000100          D
11000000          ?
00001100          ?
00000000
00001100          ?
00000000
00000001          ?
00000000
00000000
00011100          ?
00100000
00000000
00001000
00000101          ?
01011111          _
01101000          h
01110100          t
01110100          t
01110000          p
11000000          ?
01000100          D
out of range      out of range
out of range      out of range
[...]
```

I don't understand why I don't have enough data here. Truncation bit is set to false, so I should have all data in this packet, the `01101100` really means a size of 108, and I've only ~75 bytes here. So what am I doing wrong? This problem seems to happens mostly with packets containing answers.

Comment: show some code, so we can see what your are doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the problem was that the protocol has a compression defined. If the size of the next chains starts with 11xx xxxx, it means it's a pointer to a previous string, xx xxxx is the byte index of the stream.

I wasn't reading this, meaning that I was reading the 11xx xxxx has a length, giving me an huge length that was frequently out of range.